# Double pop-up window close and refresh main page

Tags: php, popupwindow

I have a php programme where on first click I open a pop-up a window and via it I open another window. In the second pop-up window I got this codes.

```
if($rollBackStatus=="False")
  {
    mysqli_commit($link);
    $statusShow=0;
    echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\" charset=\"utf-8\">var s=window.opener;s.close();</script>";
    echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\" charset=\"utf-8\">window.self.close()</script>";

  }
```

This works fine but what need is that after both the pop-up message close to refresh the main page? I know of this codes  window.opener.location.reload(); but how to apply in this scenario?

Comment: Not sure if this is what you’re asking, but it should be possible to “nest” opener references – your first popup has an `opener`, and `window.opener` refers to that first popup from your second – so `window.opener.opener` should work to access your originating window from withing the second popup. (But IMHO terrible UX, multiple popups …)

Comment: I know is terrible but I got no option on the flow. So what you suggesting is window.opener.opener.location.reload()?